# Is there a ConvertCSVtoSQL processor in NiFi, if not what would substitute?

Tags: python, oracle, csv, apache-nifi

Apache-NiFi:
I want to read in a file and Extract any text within that file then I would like to take the text attributes from that file and generate a csv representation. There is a ConvertJSONtoSQL processor which I would use to to prepare the data to go into the database, is there a ConvertCSVtoSQL processor [i.e. the reason I am missing number 4 below]? If not, what would work?

The current processors in my dataflow in nifi:

1. Getfile [will later change to ConsumeEWS]
2. ExtractText
3. AttributetoCSV
4. **is there a ConvertCSVtoSQL processor??
5. PutSQL

Comment: CSV is data.  SQL is a language. You can use SQL to insert CSV easily.  One example is [samples/load_csv.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/load_csv.py)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do the 4th step like this

`ConvertRecord` (CSV->JSON) -> `ConvertJSONtoSQL`

So it's a hack where you convert the CSV flowfiles into JSON structure using the `ConvertRecord` by setting the `RecordReader` as CSV and `RecordWriter` as JSON.

Then just use the `ConvertJSONtoSQL` to generate the SQL commands that you would like to perform.